# Null pointer exception in Java while calling the library

Tags: selenium

Now i modified the code but still i am getting Null Pointer Exception

Below is my modified code
   enter code here

```
package lib;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
//@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Login {
WebDriver driver;
@BeforeMethod
void Initalisation()
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Eclipse\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capability=new DesiredCapabilities();
    capability.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    InternetExplorerDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(capability);
    driver.get("http://segotn11540.rds.volvo.com/vss_connect_testr1/Login/Login.aspx");

}

public Login(String UserName,String BrandName)
{

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='UserNameInputText']")).sendKeys(UserName);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Brand']")).sendKeys(BrandName);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='CmdLogin']")).click();
    String Title=driver.getTitle();

    if(!Title.contains("VSS 4.0"))
            {
        System.out.println(UserName+""+"does not exists");
        driver.quit();
            }
    CheckForCancel();
}
private void CheckForCancel() {
    if(!driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel")).isEmpty())
    {
    driver.findElement(By.id("Cancel")).click();
    }

}
```

}

Now I will create the main Java file

> Blockquote
>   This will initalise the login with the parameters supplied

```
Import Login library
public class MessageBoard {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Login login=new Login("TYP40FI","Volvo");

}


}
```

What is wrong in above code

Comment: Please, insert the exception trace

Comment: Initialize `driver` variable . [And check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the driver variable as
`WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();`

Comment: Do i need to do in Main Program

Comment: do it in the Login and Initialisation classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Login(String UserName,String BrandName)
```

{

```
//Add this line in your code as you are trying in IE
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='UserNameInputText']")).sendKeys(UserName);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Brand']")).sendKeys(BrandName);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='CmdLogin']")).click();
String Title=driver.getTitle();

if(!Title.contains("VSS 4.0"))
        {
    System.out.println(UserName+""+"does not exists");
    driver.quit();
        }
CheckForCancel();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Debug and check: Is `Initalisation()` being called in the beginning?
2. Usually `@BeforeMethod` is called before test starts, so where is your `@Test` function. (syntax could be wrong)
3. If you don't really care about `@Test` property, that means your Main function needs to call `Initalisation()` before calling `Login(...)`, otherwise the driver is not set yet (aka `Null`)